# How to add data from a data source to be added in an Excel file dynamically

Tags: c#, excel

I have been trying to find out how to add cells for when I create my Excel spreedsheet using c#. I see how everyone has done it by adding a range of cells. My problem is I wont know the number of cells. I want to be able to set column headers and the data populate under them. Am I asking to much? I do not have any source code I am merely doing research before I embark on this journey. Examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I realize you are asking about Excel but let me throw out this option:  what about creating a CSV file (that can be opened in Excel)?  Sometimes using CSV is not the most elegant option but it's a bit easier and may suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what library you're using, but I use [EPPLus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/) in my current development and it works like a charm.  When you view their CodePlex page, just scroll down to see some examples and screenshots to give you an idea of what you're dealing with.  The source also has a lot of examples in it.  Here's a snippet from my application:

```
// Setup a new Excel package (workbook).
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    // Create a a new worksheet in the workbook.
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Files");

    // Set the titles for the columns.
    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Date";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Time";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "File Name";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Location";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Size";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value = "Comments";

    // Set formatting for the titles.
    using (var range = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 6])
    {
        range.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        range.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.RoyalBlue);
        range.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
        range.Style.WrapText = true;
    }

    // Set the titles to repeat.
    worksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatRows = new ExcelAddress("1:1");

    // Set worksheet to print in landscape.
    worksheet.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Landscape;

    // Set the worksheet to fit all columns.
    worksheet.PrinterSettings.FitToPage = true;
    worksheet.PrinterSettings.FitToWidth = 1;
    worksheet.PrinterSettings.FitToHeight = 0;

    // Set the border to separate data.
    worksheet.Cells.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    worksheet.Cells.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    worksheet.Cells.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    worksheet.Cells.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;

    for (int i = 0, row = 2; i < files.Count; i++, row++)
    {
            worksheet.Cells[String.Format("A{0}", row)].Value = files[i].Date;
            worksheet.Cells[String.Format("B{0}", row)].Value = files[i].Time;
            worksheet.Cells[String.Format("C{0}", row)].Value = files[i].FileName;
            worksheet.Cells[String.Format("D{0}", row)].Value = files[i].Location;
            worksheet.Cells[String.Format("E{0}", row)].Value = files[i].Size;
            worksheet.Cells[String.Format("E{0}", row)].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0";
            worksheet.Cells[String.Format("F{0}", row)].Value = files[i].Comments;
    }

    // Auto fit all columns.
    worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

    package.Save();
}
```

As you see, it's rather straightforward and you can make it as dynamic as you want.